# Guardar valores com o comando "for"

Tags: matlab

Minha dúvida:

Como posso guardar os valores do comando 'for' dos objetos que possuírem área maior que 50? Preciso guardar os números desses objetos pq posteriormente irei calcular a distância entre dois deles, alguém saberia como guardar esses valores?

Código:

```
original = imread('A.jpg');
verde = original(:,:,2) > 250;
imshow(verde);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(verde, 'noholes');
stats = regionprops(L, 'Area');
qtd_verde = sum([stats.Area] > 50);
imshow(original);

hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
    area = stats(k).Area;

    if area > 50
        boundary = B{k};
        plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'black', 'LineWidth', 2);
        text(boundary(1,2), boundary(1,1), sprintf('%.0f',k),...
            'Color', 'white',...
            'FontSize', 12,...
            'FontWeight', 'bold',...
            'BackgroundColor', 'black');


    end
end
hold off
```

@EDIT

Consegui resolver selecionando a forma geométrica que me interessava, no caso um retângulo, logo irá aparecer apenas os dois objetos 'sempre'. Mas caso alguém saiba como resolver o problema anterior, seria bastante interessante e me ajudaria bastante!

```
original = imread('A.jpg');
verde = original(:,:,2) > 218;
imshow(verde);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(verde, 'noholes');
MN = [3 15];
SE = strel('rectangle', MN);
Iopenned = imopen(L,SE);
imshow(Iopenned);
%=============
[J,H] = bwboundaries(Iopenned, 'noholes');
stats = regionprops(Iopenned, 'Area');
qtd_verde = sum([stats.Area] > 50)
imshow(original);
title(sprintf('\\fontsize{16}{Existem %d objetos verdes nessa imagem}', qtd_verde));

hold on
for k = 1:length(J)
    boundary = J{k};
    plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'black', 'LineWidth', 2);
    text(boundary(1,2), boundary(1,1), sprintf('%.0f',k),...
        'Color', 'white',...
        'FontSize', 12,...
        'FontWeight', 'bold',...
        'BackgroundColor', 'black');



end
hold off
```

Comment: Editado, mas caso alguém saiba resolver o problema inicial, comenta aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza se meu método funciona com o seu sistema, pois não sei exatamente o que vc precisa guardar, pois não consigo rodar seu código (não tenho a sua imagem, caso você comente, posso alterar de acordo). 
Porém, mesmo que vc tenha uma `cell`, é possível usar este método (use a função `cell(m,n,p)`), basta fazer a declaração e copias apropriadamente.

Eu fiz uma declaração inicial de um contador `jj` e uma matriz `savedindex` pra armazenar os dados. Depois do `for` loop, eu corto os zeros que estão sobrando da matrix.

```
b=rand(50,1); %data qq pra testar

jj=1; %temp index
savedindex=zeros(numel(b),1); %Declara a matriz
for ii=1:numel(b);

    if b(ii)>0.5,

        %faz o que vc precisa e...

        %Salva o indice
        savedindex(jj)=ii;
        jj=jj+1;%aumenta pra proxima iteracão
    end

end

savedindex=savedindex(1:(jj-1),1);%recorta os zeros não utilizados da matriz
```